# Finding any path on a binary matrix

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to write a C program that follow 1s to the left or down printing out 1s for horizontal moves 2s for vertical.It doesn`t have to be the shortest path or calculate every path.I tried to write it recursively but I am very new to it.

```
char check_path(char *table,int current_row,int current_col);
int current_row=0,current_col=0;

int main()
{
    int i,j,row,col,current_row,current_col;
    char table[30][30];
    
    printf("Matrisin satir sayisini giriniz : ");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("Matrisin sutun sayisini giriniz : ");
    scanf("%d",&col);
    

    
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            printf("1 ya da 0 olacak sekilde %d. satir ve %d. sutundaki elemani giriniz : ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&table[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    check_path(table,0,0);
    
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", table[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}

char check_path(char *table,int current_row,int current_col)
{
    if (*(*(table+current_row)+current_col+1) != 0)
    {
        *(*(table+current_row)+current_col+1) = '-';
        printf("1\t");
        return check_path(table,current_row,current_col+1);
        
    }

    else
    {   
        current_col=0;
        printf("2\t");
        return check_path(table,current_row+1,current_col);

    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand your question. Perhaps an example of expected input/output would be helpful. A quick glance at your code says that you always allow moving to the next row, no matter what is below you; is that really allowed? You always move horizontally if possible, can that not lead you to a dead end?

Comment: Your question is not written in clear English.  On the other hand, if you are beginner, you should not use constructs such as `(*(*(table+current_row)+current_col+1) != 0)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.